# Why do I not have the ability to add new issues in Redmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I've set up Redmine successfully, but for some reason no user is capable of adding new issues to a project, even when that person is admin or has a role with every permission checked. This is redmine version 3.2.2, the latest stable release.

While setting up the webapp, rake db:migrate ran with no errors, bundle install went off without a hitch, and all other features seem to work. I've attached a screenshot and circled in red where I believe the "new issues" tab should be.

[image: Projects page where new issues tab should be]

PS: Sorry if I don't include information you may need to answer this question. I would love to provide more info but I'm not certain what's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem a few days ago when I loaded up an earlier version of Redmine (2.1.2)

Version 2.1.2 has the new issues tab already on the project's page, but will give a message saying the user has to create a default issue status in the administration page. Adding an issue status and new tracker on the administrator's page allowed me to add new issues to projects in the latest version of Redmine. For some reason they eliminated this helpful message in later versions.

Answer (score 4):

Usual this happens when a project have no a tracker. You can choice some trackers for a project on a project's setting page.

Comment: New issue status and trackers must be created on the administrator's page, not the project's setting page

Comment: Yes You right but if You unselect all trackers in a project a tab 'new issue' won't show